# Why does FirstOrDefault call SaveChanges?

Tags: winforms, entity-framework-5

In the following code ConfigSetting is an entity and Db is my Context.
When I step into the following line in my debugger

```
 ConfigSetting config = this.Db.ConfigSettings.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == kSiteGuid);
```

I find I am in the context SaveChanges event.

The database already exists so EF should not be trying to seed it.

The call stack is

> SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.dll!SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context.SaveChanges() Line 338    C#
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase() + 0x9e bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.SeedDatabase() + 0x40 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable pendingMigrations, string targetMigrationId, string lastMigrationId) + 0x38c bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Upgrade(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable pendingMigrations, string targetMigrationId, string lastMigrationId) + 0x5e bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(string targetMigration) + 0x547 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() + 0x34 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion.InitializeDatabase(SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context context) + 0xa3 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializerInternal.AnonymousMethod_*0(System.Data.Entity.DbContext c) + 0xd0 bytes
>
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization.AnonymousMethod*_6() + 0x55 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(System.Action action) + 0x74 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() + 0x17d bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase.AnonymousMethod__4(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext c) + 0x30 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction.PerformAction(System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext input) + 0xa2 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(System.Action action) + 0x181 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() + 0xa5 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() + 0x46 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(System.Type entityType) + 0x2d bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet.Initialize() + 0x97 bytes
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet.InternalContext.get() + 0x32 bytes 
>       EntityFramework.dll!System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery.System.Linq.IQueryable.Provider.get() + 0x8c bytes
>       System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(System.Linq.IQueryable source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> predicate) + 0x55 bytes
>       SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.dll!SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.DataHelper.FindOrCreateSite() Line 262 + 0x1d6 bytes  C#
>       SBD.Syrius.UI.exe!SBD.Syrius.UI.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 34 + 0x24 bytes    C#
>       [Native to Managed Transition]
>       [Managed to Native Transition]
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(System.ActivationContext activationContext, string[] activationCustomData) + 0x66 bytes 
>       Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone() + 0x8d bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x285 bytes 
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x9 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x57 bytes
>       mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x51 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

The Debugger shows

> 'SBD.Syrius.UI.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'E:\EShared\Syrius6\syrius_syrius\SBD.Syrius.UI\bin\Debug\SBD.Syrius.Synchronisation.dll', Symbols loaded.
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>   Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateActivator.AnonymousMethod__0'
>   Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance'
>   Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase'

[update]

Information about the initializer

```
    private static string _connectionString;

    public Context()
        : base(_connectionString )
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());

    }

    public Context(string connString)
        : base(connString)
    {

        _connectionString = connString;
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());


    }

    public Context(string connString )
        : base(connString)
    {
        _connectionString = connString;

    }
```

For the Configuration class

```
namespace SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Migrations
{

  using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;


  public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context>
  {
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(SBD.Syrius.DataLayer.Context context)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide the debugger?

Comment: done, also i disabled "just my code" and was able to see the call stack

Comment: You should show your Application_Start method, or wherever you're configuring your EF initialization.

Comment: I don't think MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion is what you want.  I think that forces a migration, but I could be wrong.

Comment: That would explain it. The Up() methods in the migration aren't being called. Probably because the database structure is up to date.  It just seems confusing that SaveChanges is called when it needn't be.  Is there a better way of checking whether a migration is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the call stack, you can see that it's going through a database migration.  This is the process that occurs when you make a change to your model, and the database structure needs to be updated.

After the migration occurs, EF then calls SeedDatabase, which allows you to add default values.  At the end of SeedDatabase, it calls SaveChanges to save those changes.

Comment: I agree it looks like this, however i have not made a change to my model. If I run Add_migration in PM> the created migration has no code.

Comment: It's calling InitializeDatabase.  Did you set the DbInitializer to null?

Comment: i didnt set the initialiser to null because i want the initialise to occur if the database has been dropped.

Answer (score 0):

This exception was called in the GenericRepository.cs for my UnitOfWork when I tried to create a new entity.

```
 public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

**Easy Fix**

In the Package Manager Console. Add a new migration `Add-Migration SomeMeaninglessName` and updated the database `Update-Database`.